# curl GET send JSON as HTTP parameter

Tags: curl, get, curly-braces

I'm trying to send a message to AWS SQS from bash script using curl. I took this [article](https://geek.co.il/2014/11/19/script-day-amazon-aws-signature-version-4) as a base. As a result I'm building the following request:
https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/[MY_QUEUE_NAME]?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=[MY_MESSAGE]

And here starts the most complicated. Whenever I'm using a plain text as MY_MESSAGE everything works perfect and message is delivered to SQS, but I want to send a JSON: 
{"mahine": "SOME_MACHINE", "user": "SOME_USER"}

I haven't found a way to use curly braces in GET request as HTTP parameter. How can I make {} symbols be recognized as simple text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really you should be adding it to the request body in a `POST` with something like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -X POST \
     -d '{"machine":"SOME_MACHINE","user":"SOME_USER"}' \
     https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/[MY_QUEUE_NAME]?Action=SendMessage
```

You can however add JSON to a GET request in the URL but you will need to `encode` it first using percent escaping (i.e. %20 escapes a space). `{` and `}` are not valid in a URL and need to be encoded to `%7B` and `%7D` receptively.

You can use this [URL encoder](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to encode your JSON to an acceptable format for the URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot, after encoding the whole message issue was resolved